# Change part of a src of an iframe inside a div

Tags: javascript, iframe, replace, src

I want to replace part of the src of an iframe that is inside some divs on the webpage.
I've searched the web and i came up with this. I tried to select the iframe by it's class which is photoset.

> var src= $(this).attr('src').replace('/400/','/380/');
>   $('iframe.photoset').attr('src', src);

This isn't working, but i searched and search and i can't seem to find the error.
Can you guys help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the rule "better late than ever" will apply this time - this should do the work:

```
var src = $(this).attr('src').replace('400','380'); 
$('iframe.photoset').attr('src', src);
```

or if you want to replace every "400" in a string:

```
var src = $(this).attr('src').replace(/400/g,'380'); 
$('iframe.photoset').attr('src', src);
```